# Using Kirchhoff's laws to find currents

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

> There are four resistors, R1=25Ω,R2=15Ω,R3=40Ω, R4=20Ω that are
>   connected to an element 12V as shown in the figure.  Find the current in each
>   resistor.

[image: Figure 1]

$I_1=I_2+I_3$, where $I_1$ is the current rotating clockwise around $R_1$, $R_3$ and $R_4$, $I_2$ is the current flowing downwards through $R_3$ and $I_3$ is the current flowing downwards through $R_4$. This equation comes from Kirchoff's Law, whihch states that in any junction, the total amount of current in must equal the total amount of current out, in other words $\sum I=0$

I am approaching this problem by finding three different expressions that include $I_1, I_2, I_3$ and then solve for all the $I$'s using a matrix (I use the matrix for speed, but it can also be done by hand).

Thus I attempt to find one of these expressions using the equation $\sum \varepsilon=\sum IR$. I know that $\varepsilon=12$, seeing as the battery has $12V$.

So do I have to find an equation $12=I_1R+I_2R+I_3R+I_4R$? If so, which resitances do I use for $I_1$ for example? $25+15$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: To motivate others to answer, you need to demonstrate that you've actually attempted to solve the problem. See here for some basics of adding resistors in series or in parallel: http://physics.bu.edu/py106/notes/Circuits.html

Comment: @Pablo: It would help us greatly to answer your question if you could somehow label your currents with current arrows.  Technically, you have listed all of the information necessary.  A picture, though, is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also know that $12V=40I_1+\frac{1}{40}I_2+\frac{1}{20}I_3$ due to
>   the second law of conservation of energy.

This equation is incorrect for at least two reasons:  (1) the dimensions are inconsistent and (2) it is not consistent with Kirchhoff's voltage law (KVL).

Also, it is not clear what the "second law of conservation of energy" refers to.

Note that each term in the equation must be a voltage but the two right-most terms appear to have units of $\frac{A^2}{V}$.

The equation consistent with KVL is

$$12\,\mathrm{V} = 25\,\Omega\cdot I_1 +  R_{eq}\cdot I_1 + 15\,\Omega\cdot I_1$$

where $R_{eq}$ is the equivalent resistance of the two parallel connected resistors.   After solving for $I_1$, you can then find $I_2$ and $I_3$ with [current division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider)

---

> but I dont get why you would also multiply $I_1$ by $R_{eq}$. Doesnt $I_1$ only
>   go through resistor R1 and R2?

(1) if you combine the parallel connected $40\,\Omega$ and $20\,\Omega$ resistors into one *equivalent* resistance, then the current $I_1$ is through that equivalent resistance

(2) you actually have already stated this in your question when you wrote $I_1 = I_2 + I_3$

I think one of the key misconceptions you have is that the voltage across the two resistors mentioned above *add* together as if these resistors are series connected.

The fact is that, since they are parallel connected, they have identical voltage across

$$40\,\Omega \cdot I_2 =  20\,\Omega \cdot I_3 = R_{eq}\cdot\left(I_2 + I_3\right) = R_{eq}\cdot I_1$$

where I assume $I_2$ is the current through the $40\,\Omega$ resistor and $I_3$ is the current through the $20\,\Omega$ resistor.

In you KVL equation, you must count this voltage just once.  Now, take this information and solve your circuit and post the solution as an answer to your own question and then accept it.

Comment: thank you for your answer! However I dont fully understand how you got the equation you wrote here. I understand why it would be $25 \Omega \cdot I_1+ 15 \Omega \cdot I_1$, but I dont get why you would also multiply $I_1$ by $R_{eq}$. Doesnt $I_1$ only go through resistor $R1$ and $R2$? Thanks again :)

Comment: @Pablo, I've update my answer to address your comment.